# Not a Levy on Me

Tags: riddle, word

Never living, but bearing life within.
Often monochromatic, all around the world.

Can be found on your phone, nowadays.
Lined up together, taken in order.
Under a label proclaiming its nature.
Essential in some situations.

Handing over money to escape:
Every usage costs you dear.
Raise your hand when in need:
Each city has them everywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My take on this, which is not a levy on me is:

> **Taxi** - which doesn't mean tax I.

Never living, but bearing life within. Often monochromatic, all around the world.

> Cars with a driver & passengers. One colour, say black in London and yellow in New York.

Can be found on your phone, nowadays. Lined up together, taken in order.

> There are phone apps to order a taxi. They park in a rank, and you take the one in front.

Under a label proclaiming its nature. Essential in some situations.

> A taxi sign or light on top. Take one to get somewhere quick with no other transport.

Handing over money to escape: Every usage costs you dear.

> Taxis fares are relatively expensive.

Raise your hand when in need: Each city has them everywhere.

> May put your hand up to flag a taxi, which are common in cities.

Comment: Tom strikes again! Correct and well done.